# Excel - Lookup between three tables

Tags: excel, lookup

[image]

I am using Excel 2010. I have three tables: Code, Name and Region.
I would like to populate Region table with the values you can see. I would like to count the number of instances where Region appears in the Name Table, and what code is attributed to the name in the Code table.
I understand a lookup column on the Name Table with the Code would be sensible idea however, I'm curious as to whether this could be done without.
Thanks in advance for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Code[[Name]:[Name]],Name[[Name]:[Name]],Code[[Code]:[Code]],Region[[#Headers],[A]])*(Name[[Region]:[Region]]=Region[@[Region]:[Region]]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the left top cell in your picture is A1, the following formula should be pasted in H3 and can be copied pasted in the third table.

=COUNTIFS($B:$B;H$1;$E:$E;$G2)